# Chrome Extension - How to execute a javascript file with button click function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, execute

i read many documents about this but i couldnt figure out that. I need help about execute another js when button clicked.
test.js is my javascript file to execute. And in that file there is a just one line code like "alert("test.js executed!");

In my javascript file my click function is like that.

```
$("#src").click(function(){
    alert("hi");
});
```

It's working well, i need to execute my "test.js" script. Like this:

```
$("#src").click(function(){
    alert("hi");
    $.getScript("javascript/test.js",function(){

    })
    .success(function(){
        alert("success");
    })
    .error(function (){
        alert("Failed to execute script");
    });
});
```

But nothing happens. No errors aswell. How can i execute that script with click ?

Comment: What exactly is it that you need to run in test.js?

If it's just a function, then rather import test.js on your page and call that function directly in the click listener.

Comment: No not just a function, there a many codes includes functions too.

Answer (score 1):

That would fall under the use of `eval`, since that's exactly what `getScript` does.

This is [not allowed by the default Chrome extension CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSEval) and for a good reason.

You could argue that if the script is included with your extension, the security risk is non-existent,and you can override the CSP to allow that. It's bad and sloppy though.

Ideally, you want to simply include `test.js` with a `<script>` tag into the page, and call some function in it instead. Might need some modification on the file, but this is the proper way to do it.

If you *absolutely* need to execute the whole `test.js` every time (though there is no reason for it), create and append a `<script>` element with `src` appropriately set. This does not violate the CSP.